# Is it possible to build an activity feed using Django commenting?

Tags: ios, django, json, feed, django-comments

Dear stackoverflowers,

Is it possible to build an activity feed using Django commenting?

For example, In the 'home' view of my professional photography iOS app, I would like to fill it with actions via JSON such as:

User1 commented on User2's photo: Looks amazing

User 1 started following User2 and User3

User1 liked User2's photo

User3 liked 6 photos

Is this possible? and if so how can this be done?

Comment: This is kind of a vague question.  If you change enough stuff you can do anything you want!  How exactly do you want to "use" Django commenting?  Use the comment rendering logic to pull info on activities from another model, or write a "comment" in the database every time an activity takes place?  Also, even if you can do it with the commenting system, there may be no benefit over doing it in another fashion.  Generally this site favors more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following app: [django-activity-stream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/)